# Execute 1 spring batch job at one time

Tags: spring-batch

I am having mule application where I received messages from queues. There are 2 types of messages I received on 1 queue. 1 is pipe separated and another one is xml messages. Both the messages stored data in same table. After getting the messages(pipe separated and xml) from mule I am passing those messages to Job parameters so that jobs can pick up those messages and process it. I have 2 jobs one for processing pipe separated messages and another one to process xml messages. As soon as I received message on queue I pass those messages to the jobs. Now I want If I am receiving pipe separated messages(more than 60000 messages) I want my xml message process job should wait till I finished consumption of pipe separated messages.

Thanks
Sachin

Comment: Not enough information.  How are you launching the jobs?

Comment: Hi Michael,  I have updated my question. Hope now it will be clear.